# How does GHC handle typeclass and instance in core?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I compiled the following Haskell code to core:

```
class FunClass a where
  functionInClass :: a -> ()

data MyData = MyData
data YourData = YourData

instance FunClass MyData where
  functionInClass a = ()
instance FunClass YourData where
  functionInClass a = ()

valueA :: ()
valueA = functionInClass MyData

valueB :: ()
valueB = functionInClass YourData
```

and got the following core bindings (I deleted some boilerplates that are irrelavant):

```
 $cfunctionInClass :: MyData -> ()
 [LclId]
 $cfunctionInClass = \ _ [Occ=Dead] -> break<3>() ()

 $fFunClassMyData [InlPrag=INLINE (sat-args=0)] :: FunClass MyData
 $fFunClassMyData
   = $cfunctionInClass
     `cast` (Sym (N:FunClass[0] <MyData>_N)
             :: Coercible (MyData -> ()) (FunClass MyData))

 $cfunctionInClass :: YourData -> ()
 [LclId]
 $cfunctionInClass = \ _ [Occ=Dead] -> break<2>() ()

 $fFunClassYourData [InlPrag=INLINE (sat-args=0)] :: FunClass YourData
 $fFunClassYourData
   = $cfunctionInClass
     `cast` (Sym (N:FunClass[0] <YourData>_N)
             :: Coercible (YourData -> ()) (FunClass YourData))

 valueA :: ()
 [LclIdX]
 valueA
   = break<1>() functionInClass @ MyData $fFunClassMyData MyData

 valueB :: ()
 [LclIdX]
 valueB
   = break<0>()
     functionInClass @ YourData $fFunClassYourData YourData
```

My questions are:

1. Why do the two `cfunctionInClass` share the same name? How do we tell them apart?
2. What does `cast` do exactly?
3. Is there anything related to typeclass/instance outside of `mg_binds ModGuts`?

Comment: I don't think you *need* to tell them apart, because their only use seems to be in setting the values of the two distinct values `fFunClassMyData` and `fFunClassYourData`. After each call to `cast`, the value is irrelevant, and it seems like Core simply reuses the name after the first call.

Comment: @chepner Could you explain why the value is irrelevant? Also, I found that the two `cfunctionInClass` actually have different `Unique`s, which are ignored when they are outputed.

Comment: Not really; I'm unfamiliar with Core, but it *looks* like once its value is used to set `fFunClass{My,Your}Data`, its value isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing (i) exactly which version of GHC, (ii) the exact `ghc` command line you used, and (iii) the full contents of the file you compiled, it's hard to duplicate the core output you're asking about, but here are some answers:

1) When generating your core, you probably supplied the flag `-dsuppress-uniques`, used some other flag that implied it, or maybe used an older version of GHC where it was the default.  This flag causes GHC to suppress from the core output the little random suffixes used to create unique names.  If you remove the flag or add an explicit `-dno-suppress-uniques`, you should see unique names like `$cfunctionInClass_r1cH` and `$cfunctionInClass_r1dh`.

2) Core is a typed language, and the function `cast` is used (extensively) to change the types of expressions.  Note that it does not change the internal representation of the expression itself, so it can only be used to switch between types that have the same internal representation in memory.

You'll see casts all over the place for code that uses `newtypes`.  For example the code:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
inc (MyInt n) = MyInt (n + 1)
```

creates the (unoptimized) core:

```
inc1 :: MyInt -> Int
inc1
  = \ (ds :: MyInt) ->
      + @ Int $fNumInt (ds `cast` (N:MyInt[0] :: MyInt ~R# Int)) (I# 1#)
inc :: MyInt -> MyInt
inc
  = inc1
    `cast` (<MyInt>_R ->_R Sym (N:MyInt[0])
            :: (MyInt -> Int) ~R# (MyInt -> MyInt))
```

with several casts.

The way `cast` works, the left hand side of the `` `cast` `` operator is a normal core term (e.g., variable or other expression) representing the value whose type is being changed; the right hand side is something called a "coercion" which is a piece of evidence that the compiler constructs to prove that two types are representationally equivalent (i.e., have the same in-memory representation and so can be safely coerced).  For example, in my newtype example above, the coercion for the first cast:

```
N:MyInt[0] :: MyInt ~R# Int
```

is a coercion value `N:MyInt[0]` whose type is the representational equality (`~R#`) of `MyInt` and `Int`.  (Technically, `N:MyInt[0]` is a coercion *type* whose *kind* is the given representational equality, but that distinction doesn't really matter.)  If you're familiar with the Curry-Howard isomorphism, where values can be considered proofs of their types, this is an example of this in action deep in GHC's guts -- the value/type `N:MyInt[0]` proves its type/kind, namely the representational equality of the newtype and its contents, which allows the cast to take place.

In your example, the cast:

```
$fFunClassMyData [InlPrag=INLINE (sat-args=0)] :: FunClass MyData
$fFunClassMyData
  = $cfunctionInClass
    `cast` (Sym (N:FunClass[0] <MyData>_N)
            :: Coercible (MyData -> ()) (FunClass MyData))
```

is a complex way of saying that GHC represents instance dictionaries for type classes having only one function much the same way it would represent a newtype containing a function of that type which is the same way it would represent the function value itself.  Therefore, the function value `$cfunctionInClass` can be directly cast to a dictionary value.

However, if you added another function to your typeclass:

```
class FunClass a where
  functionInClass :: a -> ()
  anotherFunction :: a
```

the casts would disappear from the definition of the dictionaries, and they'd look more like what you'd expect:

```
$fFunClassMyData
$fFunClassMyData = C:FunClass $cfunctionInClass $canotherFunction
```

It's important to note that `cast` doesn't do anything in the final code.  Once the core is converted to untyped STG and eventually CMM and assembly, the `cast` calls are optimized out, as they don't affect the values, they only modify compile-time types to satisfy the core typechecker.  So, unless you're debugging GHC, you probably don't care about casts and should consider then no-ops.  You can suppress some of the detail with `-dsuppress-coercions` (implied by `-dsuppress-all`):

```
$fFunClassYourData = $cfunctionInClass1 `cast` <Co:3>
```

and just pretend `` x `cast` <Co:xxx> `` is exactly equivalent to `x`.  In your example above, the dictionary *is* just the single instance function for the typeclass, so this is really the same up to coercible types as:

```
$fFunClassMyData = $cFunctionInClass
```

3) Sure. Additional class and instance information is stored in the `mg_tcs` and `mg_insts` fields of `ModGuts`, respectively.  To a rough approximation, `mg_binds` contains the information needed for code generation while `mg_tcs` and `mg_insts` contain the information needed to generate the interface file.

#### Helpful references to GHC compiler code

`ghc/compiler/coreSyn/PprCore.hs` - Module for pretty-printing core.  If you want to know where something in core comes from, this is it.  (For example, `ppr_expr add_par (Cast expr co) = ...` is the code responsible for pretty printing `` `cast` `` operators.

`ghc/compiler/coreSyn/CoreSyn.hs` - The `Expr` type is the "core" of core.  The constructor `Cast (Expr b) Coercion` represents a cast.

`ghc/compiler/types/TycoRep.hs` - The definition of `Coercion` is here.

`ghc/compiler/main/HscTypes.hs` - The definition of `ModGuts` and the "subsets" of fields `CgGuts` used for code generation and `ModIface`/`ModDetails` used for writing the interface file and linking.

`ghc/compiler/main/TidyPgm.hs` - Definition of the function `tidyGuts`, where `ModGuts` information is split into `CgGuts` for code generation and `ModDetails`, a cached version of `ModIface` kept in memory when compiling multiple modules and/or used to generate a full `ModIface` to write out to an interface file.